# PHP href doesn't work in yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to put `href="#Modal"` into the code below for me to display my view in this specific div

```
<?php echo CHtml::linkButton(CHtml::image('', '', array( 'class'=>'btn_icon')).'Edit', array('submit'=>array('menu', 'action'=>"edit")));  ?>
```

I tried this;

```
<?php echo CHtml::linkButton(CHtml::image('', '', array('class'=>'btn_icon', 'href'=>'#modal')).'Edit', array('submit'=>array('menu', 'action'=>"edit")));  ?>
```

but it doesn't work.

Great Thanks to someone who can help me.

Comment: Check this link. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#linkButton-detail.  `$htmlOptions` is the second parameter. If you want to add `href="#Modal"` to `linkButton` then you should add that in second parameter.

Comment: @Jahanzeb    Just like this? <?php echo CHtml::linkButton(CHtml::image('','',array( 'class'=>'btn_icon')).'Edit', array('href'=>'#modal'),array('submit'=>array('menu', 'action'=>"edit")));  ?>

Comment: I can't test it right now, but please try this. `<?php echo CHtml::linkButton(CHtml::image('', '', array('class'=>'btn_icon')).'Edit', array('submit'=>array('menu', 'action'=>"edit"), 'href'=>'#modal'));  ?>`

Comment: I did test the last one you sent me and its just showing the code over my button but the first one i tried to put href in the second parameter it did work. and thanks for that helpful idea. but I think I still missing something. it did shows my div  when I click the button but it doesn't show the content. can you help me how to view actions from yii controller to some specific div.

Answer (score 0):

not very sure what you want but try this:

```
CHtml::linkButton(
    CHtml::image('','',array( 'class'=>'btn_icon')).'Edit',
    array(              
            'href'=>'#modal',
            'submit' => array('controller/edit', 'param'=>'menu')
    )
)
```

you need to modify it.